# I need to return value from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to return value from ajax  but it filled 0 every time and didn't wait for ajax process finished 
`var itemId=0;` as global value

```
getitemIDbyProductID(productId,getitemIDbyProductID_success);               
                 alert(itemID + "itemgeted")
```

I did this

```
  function getitemIDbyProductID(productId, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Cot.aspx/getitemIDbyProductID",
                data: JSON.stringify({ productId: productId }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    var value = 0;
                   value = JSON.parse(result.d);
                    itemID=callback(value)
                  callback(value);
                },
                error: function (msg) {    }
            }); 
        }

        function getitemIDbyProductID_success(total_percentage) {      
              alert(total_percentage +"fds"+itemID);
        }
```

but it didn't wait the ajax finished and gives me the itemId = undefiend

Comment: it is just hopeless trying to get the itemId value :( , what shall I do?

Comment: I assumed from the title this was a duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) (I still think it might be) but I have difficulty understanding what your exact issue is, since you don't `return` anything, and you appear to be using a callback, but you use to *set* a value *inside* your Ajax success function (?) instead of passing a value out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You're successfully setting the value here:

```
function getitemIDbyProductID_success(total_percentage) {
    itemID = total_percentage;
    alert(total_percentage +"fds"+itemID);
}
```

But then, in the code which *calls* this, you're successfully setting it *again*:

```
itemID=callback(value)
```

Since your `getitemIDbyProductID_success` doesn't return anything, the return value is `undefined`.  So basically you're unsetting `itemID` *immediately* after setting it.

Just invoke the callback, don't use its (non-extant) return value:

```
callback(value);
```

---

**Additionally**, this isn't going to do what you think:

```
getitemIDbyProductID(productId,getitemIDbyProductID_success);               
alert(itemID + "itemgeted");
```

Because `getitemIDbyProductID` performs an *asynchronous* operation.  Even once the above errors are corrected, this error still remains.  And this one is a duplicate of a *very* popular question (with answers far better than I can provide) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
getitemIDbyProductID(productId,function(val){
  itemID = val;
  alert(itemID + "itemgeted");
});
```

Basically, you have to wait before the itemID gets assigned right value.